# Generate random numbers for a non-standard beta distribution

Tags: python, random, probability, distribution

I need to generate random numbers which follows a beta distribution with the following parameters. X between [0.2,2], mean = 0.60 and std = 0.15.

I already had this code but when I summarized the mean and the std of the generated vector they do not agree with the input parameters. I am afraid that something is not working properly, can someone help?

This is the code:

```
ac,bc=0.2,2.0
mc,sc=0.6,0.15
mc = (mc-ac)/(bc-ac)
sc = (sc**2/(bc-ac)**2)**0.5
alpha_C_Crit = mc*(mc*(1-mc)/sc**2-1)
beta_C_Crit = (1-mc)*(mc*(1-mc)/sc**2-1)
C_crit= beta.rvs(alpha_C_Crit,beta_C_Crit,loc=0.2,scale=2.0,size=100000)
```

The summary of the generated vector C_crit.mean()=0.6445875200893583 (not close to 0.60) and C_crit.std()=0.16723411402825206 not that close to 0.15.

Comment: Please [edit] to tag the language/libraries being used

Comment: How big was your generated vector C?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not spotting your error (although you seem to be squaring and then square-rooting unnecessarily).  I went ahead and did my own implementation independently using `numpy`, and the following produces results with the target mean and standard deviation:

```python
import numpy

my_min = 0.2
my_max = 2.0
mu = 0.6
sigma = 0.15

# Rescale distribution to range of std beta: (0,1)
scale_factor = my_max - my_min
std_mu = (mu - my_min) / scale_factor
std_sigma = sigma / scale_factor

# Convert mu/sigma to alpha/beta as used by numpy.random.beta()
nu = std_mu * (1.0 - std_mu) / (std_sigma * std_sigma) - 1.0
alpha_param = std_mu * nu
beta_param = (1.0 - std_mu) * nu

# Generate std betas, scale and translate back to original parameterization
ary = scale_factor * numpy.random.beta(alpha_param, beta_param, 100000) + my_min
```

Analyzing the results using JMP statistical software produced the following histogram and summary statistics:

[image: Histogram and summary stats for generated sample]

This doesn't push close to the upper bound for the range, since values approaching 2.0 would be over nine standard deviations from the mean.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your valuable help. I wasn't sure about how to re-scale the alpha and beta parameters with the numpy method. Your proposal describes better the data than the my does. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: @DanielCassiani Please note [SO's guidance for responding to answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  Purely optional, but that's how things work around here.